# What is the relation between a fixed force and work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, power

How would you translate a constant force into work or energy? If I have a way to output 100KN continuously, how can I translate that into watts? Is there a formula for that translation?

Comment: To do work, you must cause the body upon which you apply the force to move through a distance.  In that case, the work done is the force times the distance moved.

Comment: And, since watts is power, the amount of work that was done divided by the time that it took to do that work is the power that was applied.

Comment: $E=W=F \cdot d$, $P=W/t$

Comment: Assuming your object moves at a constant velocity, then from P=FV and by knowing both F and V you can find the power output.

Comment: And remember that all the products you see in the comments above are scalar products of vectors, so you must take either the directions in consideration.

Comment: Actually your assumption that the output is a constant 100 kN is not very realistic. The force your device applies depends a lot on the object you apply it to. You cannot just "output" a force on nothing.

Comment: What do you not understand about the concepts of force, work, energy, and power? Translation is useless without concepts.

Answer (score 0):

A force does work if there is atleast a component of the force in the direction of displacement of the block.
The small work done $ dw $ by a constant force $ f $ in displacing the block through a small displacement $ ds $ is given by $ dw=fdscos\theta $, where $\theta$ is the angle between the force vector and the displacement vector. Since, power is work done per unit time,that is, $ p= \frac{dw}{dt} $ .

That is, $ p= fvcos\theta $, , where $\theta$ is the angle between the force vector and the velocity vector.